# Store i18n translations in activerecord — rails 3.2

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, internationalization

Are there any build-in way to store translations in database for rails 3.2?

I've find some gems like a https://github.com/svenfuchs/i18n-active_record and this doc http://rubydoc.info/docs/rails/2.3.8/I18n/Backend/ActiveRecord for 2.3 rails, but I can't find same solutions for 3.2.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, Globalize3:

- https://github.com/svenfuchs/globalize3

Good blog post on Globalize3:

- http://www.synbioz.com/blog/2012/06/27/internationalization_with_globalize

If you're curious about how to do i18n backends:

- http://guides.rubyonrails.org/i18n.html#using-different-backends

If you're curious about faster backends using Tokyo Cabinet or Redis:

- http://asciicasts.com/episodes/256-i18n-backends